# What is the difference between 'import numpy as np' and 'from numpy import array'?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Usually when ever I'm creating arrays in Numpy, I simply do

```
import numpy as np
```

What is the difference If I do?-

```
from numpy import array
```

Comment: using `from numpy import array`, you only import the `array` module. you cannot use other functions of numpy. with `import numpy as np`, you import all the numpy modules and you can use them as np.<>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
```

Imports the entire numpy library. You'd refer to it's functions / methods by prefixing each call with np. as in

```
my_array = np.array
```

on the other hand,

```
from numpy import array
```

imports just the array function / method and you can call it without prefixing it, as in...

```
my_array = array
```

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of asking 2 things at once.

**1 - Alias usage**

When using the `as` syntax you're only giving a module/libray an alias.

**2 - importing modules**
When you say `from numpy import array` you're importing the `array` module from the numpy library.

to combine those you could say:

```
from numpy import array as ar
```

After that you can call the array module from the numpy library by only saying `ar.xx`

Answer (score 0):

`as` keyword allows you to use shorthands and rename stuff. Particularly useful when you have long names or use things from that module a lot. In numpy you use a lot of stuff from it, so it's certainly better to write `np.<something>` than `numpy.<something>` when there's a lot of such calls, isn't it?

`from ... import` is just a way of importing only some components. If you use that lib a lot in your code, you do `import <module>`. If you need only some elements and names don't clash with yours, you do `from <module> import <something1>, <something2>`

**Important:** 
`from ... import` still allows `as` notation! They are not counterparts. My fav shorthand is `from pprint import pprint as pp` when debugging in the console.